# Laravel Implicit Model Route Binding and Vue JS

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js

I want to know if there is a way to automatically bind models and routes in vuejs and laravel just as one will do with just laravel. What I mean is, assuming, I want to update a certain post with a given id, In laravel I will do just this:

```
  public function edit(Request $request Post $post)
  {   

      $post->update($request->all());
    // then  I will return some view or do some redirect here

   }
```

Notice that I did not have to specify the post id because laravel automatically does that behind the scenes.

According what I have learned so far, using the same function with some post data from vuejs, I have first get the id by doing the following:

```
  public function edit(Request $request)
  {

   $post = $request->input('id');
   $post =  Post::where('id', $id)->first();
  // Then I perform other logic  here
  // then  I will return some view or do some redirect here

  }
```

Notice the function doesn't accept any post model anymore. If I try by adding the Model as input parameter  and calling on some edit function in vuejs do reach a route where I hit the edit in some controller, I get an internal server error 500.
Code I used is like so:

```
  public function edit(Request $request Post $post)
  {


  // Then I perform other logic  here
  // then  I will return some view or do some redirect here

  }


  //vuejs method
  editPost(post){
  var postData = {id: this.post.id};
  this.$http.post('edit/'+ postData).then((response)=>
  {
     //Some logic goes here including catch part

  });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the post id as a route parameter:

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/edit', 'PostController@edit');
```

So it will automatically inject the model instance to `post` parameter.

```
public function edit(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $post->update($request->all());
}
```

Then in your vue you can do like this:

```
editPost(post) {
    let postId = post.id;
    let postData = {
        title: '',
        content: ''
    };

    this.$http.post('posts/' + postId + '/edit', postData).then((response) => {
        //Some logic goes here including catch part
    });
}
```

Comment: This works. I have one issue left, I am using authorize method to check that only owners of posts can delete the post but I am getting a 403

Comment: When you are getting 403 that means you are not authorized to do that. You have to make sure the logged in user is the post owner.